# VB.NET (or C#) creating a Dictionary from an existing List without looping

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-objects, containers

I don't know if this is doable, maybe with Linq, but I have a `List(Of MyType)`:

```
Public Class MyType

    Property key As Char
    Property description As String
End Class
```

And I want to create a `Dictionary(Of Char, MyType)` using the key field as the dictionary keys and the values in the `List` as the dictionary values, with something like:

```
New Dictionary(Of Char, MyType)(??)
```

Even if this is doable, internally it will loop through all the List items, I guess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This purpose is fulfilled by the [`ToDictionary` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx):

```
Dim result = myList.ToDictionary(Function (x) x.key, Function (x) x.description)
```

> Even if this is doable, internally it will loop through all the List items, I guess?

Of course. In fact, an implementation without looping *is* thinkable but would result in a very inefficient look-up for the dictionary (such an implementation would create a *view* on the existing list, instead of a copy). This is only a viable strategy for *very* small dictionaries (< 10 items, say).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will loop through all the list items.  Another thing you can do is create a [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) for your list:

```
public class MyTypeCollection : KeyedCollection<char, MyType>
{
   protected override char GetKeyForItem(MyType item)
   {
      return item.key;
   }
}
```

but that won't help you adding the items.

Answer (score 2):

In C# there is the [`ToDictionary<TKey, TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx), but yes it will loop :-)

You would call it with something like: `myCollection.ToDictionary(p => p.key)`. In VB.NET I think the syntax is `myCollection.ToDictionary(Function(p) p.key)`